# PHP To Round And Add $ Sign

Tags: php, format, currency

I want to round all numbers and add a $ sign in front, no decimals.  I tried the below, and it is rounding properly, but no $ added.  What is the syntax to add in the $

```
$number = '122.86';

utf8_encode(money_format('%.0n',$number));
```

The above syntax produces 123 and my desired ouptut is $123

Comment: @chris85 -  do not follow...

Comment: Concatenate like you'd do other strings `utf8_encode('$' . money_format('%.0n',$number));`.

Comment: btw, [`money_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) doesn't work in Windows, just so you know and others visiting the question. *"The function money_format() is only defined if the system has strfmon capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is undefined in Windows."*

Comment: Is that a , or a .

Comment: see the examples in the manual

Comment: @chris85 - if I use your example syntax it adds the $ sign removes decimals, but it shows 0 for everything.  So all values are $0

Comment: I deleted my comment to use Balvinder's answer; it doesn't produce the correct output.

Comment: I posted a community wiki answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42447206/1415724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki since I based myself on [Balvinder's (original) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42447072/1).

- I don't want rep for this.

The `intval()` needs to be removed, since that will produce 122 instead of 123.

Note: 122.86 is closer to 123 than 122; basic school math teachings.

```
$number='122.86'; 
echo "$".round($number);
```

Just ["round"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) it.

Note:

[`money_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) doesn't work in Windows, just so you know and others visiting the question.

> *"The function money_format() is only defined if the system has strfmon capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is undefined in Windows."*

Comment: This produces a $ sign but 0's out all values.

Comment: @NadineSmithJonesPicard I find that rather hard to believe. I'm on Windows also and that produced `$123`

Comment: @NadineSmithJonesPicard I think you're not telling us/me the whole story. There isn't anything I can add to my answer, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Check your locale settings, as they affect the output of [`money_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).  Adding this at the top of your script should fix your issue directly, but may not be what you actually want to do:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.UTF-8');
```

The other option is to do as @chris85 suggests and just manually supply the dollar sign:

```
echo '$' . utf8_encode(money_format('%.0n',$number));
```

It may or may not be worth it to strip out any dollar signs that may or may not be present, just so you don't wind up with a double dollar sign if you deploy to a system that happens to have different configuration.

Comment: If I use the echo example, it rounds, adds the $ sign but shows a 0 for all rows

Comment: @NadineSmithJonesPicard I was just going off of your small example, sounds like you may also have some issues fetching the data that is going inside of `$number`?

Answer (score 0):

Please use round() function for round of value and concatenate with $ sign 
Use this code

```
<?php $number='122.86'; echo "$".round($number); ?>
```

Comment: close but the OP wants 123 not 122 which is what this will produce

Comment: please use ceil() function for highest value

Comment: that still produces 122

Comment: you went and edited that without marking it as an edit, am sure you just want rep, I sure don't.

Comment: $number='122.86'; echo "$".round($number); use this one

Answer (score -1):

Found your [answer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#116725) in User Contributed Notes of the PHP documentation.

```
$number = '122.86';
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.UTF-8');
echo utf8_encode(money_format('%.0n', $number));
```

Comment: This produces decimals.  My output was 0.00

Comment: Fixed. (changed `%.2n` to `$0.n`